# Visual Studio 2012 Debugging Old Code

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I have a solution with ~7 C# library projects, and a single console application. Lately when I make a change to a source file in any of the projects and press F5 to run, it appears to build and run as usual, but the executable that is running does not reflect my latest change.

If I clean, and rebuild the solution every time it works fine. This problem is local to this solution and has been replicated across multiple machines. My build configuration includes all projects in debug mode, and I have tried adding / removing projects to see if that triggers a dependency rebuild.

Any ideas on how to restore the F5 functionality?

Comment: Does you console application have explicit reference to the 7 libraries? Explicit - meaning from `Project > References > Add reference` ?

Comment: Yeah - the console references the libraries directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think console app references the library's output dll directly.  Instead you should use `Project Reference` this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple fix, might be a solution to your problem.
[Configurations Manager projects unchecked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726034/visual-studio-2012-not-detecting-file-changes)

This worked for me. I had opened the Configurations Manager before and must have unchecked the build options.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we got 2 solutions:

(1) temporary, delete local solution folder and re-get the code from SVN so you really get fresh binaries after compile (until we did find the real issue)

(2) permanent, real issue existed because a wrong order of the calls like:

IUnityContainer.Resolve()
or

IUnityContainer.Resolve()
as the order of types was very important, even there was no showing compilation or runtime error