# Visual Studio 2012 not debugging current solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

My Visual Studio 2012 Professional doesn't debug as it should.

It looks like VS is debugging old versions of my projects.
I tried debugging several projects but the same problem occurs with all of them, even when I start a new project (both console applications and windows forms applications).

It doesn't even hit the breakpoints I place right at the start of the program.

Things i've tried:

• cleaning and rebuilding my solution

• DEBUG -> options and settings -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run. Here I unchecked "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" and selected "Always build " from the "On Run, when projects are out of date" list

• deleting the .suo file (since the problem not project related I didn't expect it to be the solution but it was worth a shot).

As far as I know I didn't make any other changes to any property and I didn't perform any updates just before this issue started.

The following link descibes a similar issue but it doesn't contain a solution that works for me.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23e70e79-970d-423f-b434-12681b88ef2c/visual-studio-2012-debug-runs-old-code?forum=vsdebug

Superman also had a similar problem but again no suitable solution but in my case cleaning and rebuilding doesn't temporarily solve the problem.
[Visual Studio 2012 Debugging Old Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945493/visual-studio-2012-debugging-old-code)

any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a repair/reinstall of Visual Studio from the control panel ?

Also it could be related to a windows User profile issues. Assuming you are using Windows 7 you can try re-creating the profile using this post. http://www.techstaty.com/how-to-rebuild-a-windows-7-user-profile-the-correct-way/